# Jquery $ajax POST data and get a response mysqli_insert_id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am posting data to a PHP page using the $.ajax in Jquery. So far all this is working fine.

Here is how all this looks in my **index.html**.

```
function send() {
  $( "#send" ).show( "slow" );

var page = Page;
var title = $("#title").text();
var title_2 = $("#title_2").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "save.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { MyPage : page, My_Title1 : title, My_Title2 : title_2 },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(result.last_id);
    },
    error: function(output) {
    alert("not working whole process");
    }
});
```

This to sum up what I am doing, is sending some data, Html and contents in div's, to a sql database.

What I would like to do now is that once this data is posted to the **save.php** file, I get a response from the php sending me the ID of the page I have saved all this in. So I am using `mysqli_insert_id($con);` to acheive this.

Set it it looks like this.

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

When I execute all this, the Post works fine and I end up with what I want.
{"last id":265} at the end of my post.

```
$data['last id'] = $last_id;
echo json_encode($data);
```

How do I get this value back to my **index.html** so that I can place it inside a input. The success is not working out.

//**Reply to Steves answer**

@ Steve. Thank you for answering. Your answer is exactly what is happening. I am sending a whole bunch of html to my **save.php** file so it can save it to a sql table. 
Something looking like this.

```
Write to MySQL OK!<br>INSERT INTO Project(ID_User,Name_Project,Page_Project,Date_Project) VALUES ( 110, '\"Project name here\"', '<div class=\"file_save_container\"> <------------- HERE THERE IS A WHOLE BUNCH OF HTML ------------> </div>\n\n\n', '2015-03-19 13:10:23');<br>
```

This is all saving properly to my sql table. What I would like to achieve here is that when the ajax is sent to my **save.php** I get a response sending me the id of the newly created Project so that I can then place the response "the id" inside a . Right now mysqli_insert_id is placing this at the end of my post.

```
<br>{"this_id":"311"}
```

This is what I would like to get back as a response to my **index.html** file and not have it at the end of my post.

Comment: the `jQuery.parseJSON` is superfluous, you already set `dataType` as `JSON`

Comment: `"The success is not working out."` Please explain - what is happening? Do you get an alert?

Comment: Is this typo part of the problem `dataType: 'json,` should be `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: yes I am getting a alert with "not working whole process".

Comment: dataType: 'json, you are missing another ' after json
and 
send back "insert-id" not "insert id" because, json will make this an object and "insert id" is not a valid object key.
When you do that.. you have your id saved in "data.insert-id" so in your success: function(data){
do:
console.log(data.insert-id);

Comment: So you error function is being called - Look in the network tab or your browsers developers tools and see what the actual response being sent back is.

Comment: The response I am getting is all the html I am sending and at the end of all this the ID is posted in a json format like this {"last_id":286}

Comment: can you post save.php?

Comment: My post looks something like this. Just shortened in the middle.    Write to MySQL OK!<br>INSERT INTO Projet(ID_Adherent,Name_Projet,Page_Projet,Date_Projet) VALUES ( 110, '\"Project name here\"', '<div class=\"file_save_container\"> <------------- HERE THERE IS A WHOLE BUNCH OF HTML ------------> </div>\n\n\n', '2015-03-19 13:10:23');<br>{"last_id":292}

Comment: @AdrienBoufflet Please edit your question to show the contents of `save.php`. I am 99% sure the issue is that you are sending html as well as json - you should not send **anything** other than the json string, even a blank space will case a failure

Comment: I have just edited my question. Hope this helps to make things a little clearer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in save.php

Answer (score 0):

Write `$data['last_id']` instead of `$data['last id']` to match your JS.